# Java job execution multithreaded with executorservice?

Tags: java, multithreading, task, executorservice

How to i implement such a function ?

I have a dynamic queue which gets filled at unknown times with runnables, which have to be executed. The ExecutorService should only start a limited amount of threads, when the maximum thread size is reached, it should stop executing more threads, until one thread finishes, then the next task should be executed.

So far i came across this:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                databaseConnectionQueue);
```

The ExecutorService is created before the queue is filled, and should stay alive until the queue is deleted, not when its empty, because this can happen. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` will will not shutdown when it is empty. From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has no remaining
>   threads will be shutdown automatically.

Comment: So i would have to reference the executor in every thread (main function starts threads, to do some calculations, these threads fill the databaseConnectionQueue), do prevent it from the GC?

Comment: If it is referenced once, it's enough to not be garbage-collected, no need to reference it everywhere.

Comment: I dont get how to make the executorservice run the runnable from the queue, how so i do that, or is it implizitly done when i add the runnable to the queue?

Comment: Yes, the executor will execute the threads available on the queue automatically.

Comment: does this answers your question? @Synturas as far as i understood your query is regarding executor service which run limited number of threads. You may like to elaborate your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use FixedThreadPool (Executors.newFixedThreadPool)

As per javadoc [**Executors.newFixedThreadPool**]

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown.

Hope it helps. Thanks.